# gamma ray detection for germanium detectors

Tags: nuclear-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, particle-detectors, gamma-rays

High purity germanium detectors based on a semiconductor and  For radiation detection, the germanium detector is the best, but I confused because The functioning of a Ge detector is based on the use of the depletion region formed between two different (p and n-type) semiconductor materials.The operation of the detector is based on the interaction of gamma rays and the semiconductor within this depletion region. Why gamma rays just interact with depletion region?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285837/dead-layers-in-hpge-gamma-semiconductor-detectors

Comment: The interact throughout the volume of the detector. However, you only get a signal from interactions (charge generation) within the depletion region.

Comment: thanks but why we just obtain a signal from the depletion region I mean gamma rays interact with ions which are at the end of the p- type region or at the end of n- type region. Why we could not get a signal from there.

Comment: Because you only get charge separation yielding net current in the depletion region.

Comment: @JonCuster - shouldnt you answer the question then? It always pops up to me and I always think you have basically already given the answer... Somebody should...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Custer has responded first in the comment, but doesnt continue with the answer.  I think the question should have an answer to keep the Physics SE complete and useful for later searches....

Here is a cut through the HPGe detector. Pay attention to

- Al window layer
- top Ge dead layer

[image]

The usual configuration is that you put the source at a distance $d$ in the axis. The photons that you detect

- come directly from the source
- come indirectly from the source - they are scattered back from surrounding material to the detector
- come from elsewhere, but not your source

Only those coming directly are usually interesting for you. **But** they can

- scatter on **Al window or Ge dead layer** and you will see just a remains of the original energy.
- pass through totally and you see nothing
- scatter in the **active Ge** and fly away and you see just a part of the original energy (single escape and double escape effects we can put also in this point)

So what remains in the **full-energy peak** are just those lucky photons that loose all their energy in **active Ge** by one or more step effects. Mention the term **full-energy**. The background in the picture comes from those unlucky photons.
[image]